# Maximizing number of factors contributing in the sum of sorted array bounded by a value

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a sorted array of integers of size n. These values are not unique. What I need to do is
: Given a B, I need to find an `i<A[n]` such that the sum of `|A[j:1 to n]-i|` is lesser than B and to that particular sum contribute the biggest number of A[j]s. I have some ideas but I can't seem to find anything better from the naive n*B and n*n algorithm. Any ideas about O(nlogn) or O(n) ?
For example: Imagine

> A[n] = 1 2 10 10 12 14 and B<7 then the best i is 12 cause I achieve having 4 A[j]s contribute to my sum. 10 and 11 are also equally good i's cause if i=10 I got 10 - 10 + 10 - 10 +12-10 + 14-10 = 6<7

Comment: Must the numbers you pick be contiguous? For example, would it be possible to pick `1 10 14`?

Comment: I wasn't precise enough. Yeah they must be contiguous

Comment: If you pick `12`, you can do `1-12 + 2-12 + 10-12 + 10-12 + 12-12 + 14-12 < 7`. So why is the best answer 4? Must the sum also be positive maybe?

Comment: @IVlad I think it is sum of absolute values so the score in your case is |1-12|+|2-12|+... which is >7

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz - oh, right, my bad.

Comment: Exactly as Peter said. Notice that we are talking about absolute values

Comment: @Paramar There is a space between 1 and 2, I think it should be 12 (A[0])

Comment: @Paramar It is 1 2. My fault... I don't quite understand it.

Comment: No it should not. We start de facto by a sorted array A[0] =1 and A[1] = 2

Comment: Can the contiguous values of A[j] you are choosing start and end anywhere?  For example, if you had 1,1,1,1,1,7 and B=2, would you be allowed to choose the first 5 values?

Comment: Of course. There aren't any constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it in O(n) using these three tricks:

### CUMULATIVE SUM

Precompute an array C[k] that stores sum(A[0:k]).
This can be done recursively via C[k]=C[k-1]+A[k] in time O(n).
The benefit of this array is that you can then compute sum(A[a:b]) via C[b]-C[a-1].

### BEST MIDPOINT

Because your elements are sorted, then it is easy to compute the best i to minimise the sum of absolute values.  In fact, the best i will always be given by the middle entry.
If the length of the list is even, then all values of i between the two central elements will always give the minimum absolute value.

e.g. for your list 10,10,12,14 the central elements are 10 and 12, so any value for i between 10 and 12 will minimise the sum.

### ITERATIVE SEARCH

You can now scan over the elements a single time to find the best value.

```
1. Init s=0,e=0
2. if the score for A[s:e] is less than B increase e by 1
3. else increase s by 1
4. if e<n return to step 2
```

Keep track of the largest value for e-s seen which has a score < B and this is your answer.

This loop can go around at most 2n times so it is O(n).

The score for A[s:e] is given by sum |A[s:e]-A[(s+e)/2]|.

Let m=(s+e)/2.

```
score = sum |A[s:e]-A[(s+e)/2]| 
= sum |A[s:e]-A[m]|
= sum (A[m]-A[s:m]) + sum (A[m+1:e]-A[m])
= (m-s+1)*A[m]-sum(A[s:m]) + sum(A[m+1:e])-(e-m)*A[m]
```

and we can compute the sums in this expression using the precomputed array C[k].

### EDIT

If the endpoint must always be n, then you can use this alternative algorithm:

```
1. Init s=0,e=n
2. while the score for A[s:e] is greater than B, increase s by 1
```

### PYTHON CODE

Here is a python implementation of the algorithm:

```
def fast(A,B):
    C=[]
    t=0
    for a in A:
        t+=a
        C.append(t)

    def fastsum(s,e):
        if s==0:
            return C[e]
        else:
            return C[e]-C[s-1]

    def fastscore(s,e):
        m=(s+e)//2
        return (m-s+1)*A[m]-fastsum(s,m)+fastsum(m+1,e)-(e-m)*A[m]

    s=0
    e=0
    best=-1
    while e<len(A):
        if fastscore(s,e)<B:
            best=max(best,e-s+1)
            e+=1
        elif s==e:
            e+=1
        else:
            s+=1
    return best

print fast([1,2,10,10,12,14],7)
# this returns 4, as the 4 elements 10,10,12,14 can be chosen
```

Comment: I am not totally sure that I understood your algorithm I am reading it again this very moment. However I think you didn't understand what the objective is. The objective is to have the maximum number of A[j]'s taking part in the sum so that the sum is less than B,not minimizing the sum itself. In an example array 1 1 1 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 and B = 5 what would your algorithm return?

Comment: 1,1,1. It looks for the largest value of e-s. e-s equals the number of A[j]s taking part in the sum from s to e.  So I think it does maximuse the number of A[j]s taking part in the sum if I have understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in O(n) : start from the end and compute a[n]-a[n-1] :
let d=14-12 => d=2 and r=B-d => r=5,
then repeat the operation but multiplying d by 2:
d=12-10 => d=2 and r=r-2*d => r=1,
r=1 end of the algorithm because the sum must be less than B:

with a array indexed 0..n-1

```
i=1
r=B
while(r>0 && n-i>1) {
  d=a[n-i]-a[n-i-1];
  r-=i*d;
  i++;
}
return a[n-i+1];
```

maybe a drawing explains better

```
14       x
13       x  -> 2
12      xx
11      xx  -> 2*2
10    xxxx    -> 3*0
 9    xxxx   
 8    xxxx
 7    xxxx
 6    xxxx
 5    xxxx
 4   xxxxx
 3   xxxxx
 2  xxxxxx
 1 xxxxxxx
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct to me. What is the role of d? Why you multiply with 2 then with 3? Why you are sure that the last factor will be included? This algorithm does not seem correct if you have not understood the problem feel free to ask me

Comment: the d represents the difference between current element and previous when traversing the array from the end to the begin, the reason why it's multiplied by a counter is because each time an element is added the sum is impacted by the number of elements

Comment: I still do not understand it. It does not seem correct. Why do you start from the right edge of the array? Imagine an example like the following: 1 1 1 10 20 and B = 4. Your algorithm will contain only the factor 20 but the best answer is including the factors 1,1,1 (giving i the value of 1 for example)   because it contains 3 factors and your's only 1.

Comment: I though it was the positive part not absolute value

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way for an `O(N) with N size of array` approach:

```
minpos = position of closest value to B in array (binary search, O(log(N))
min = array[minpos]

if (min >= B) EXIT, no solution

// now, we just add the smallest elements from the left or the right
// until we are greater than B

leftindex = minpos - 1
rightindex = minpos + 1

while we have a valid leftindex or valid rightindex:
    add = min(abs(array[leftindex (if valid)]-B), abs(array[rightindex (if valid)]-B))
    if (min + add >= B)
        break
    min += add
    decrease leftindex or increase rightindex according to the usage

min is now our sum, rightindex the requested i (leftindex the start)
```

(It could happen that some indices are not correct, this is just the idea, not the implementation)

I would guess, the average case for small b is `O(log(N))`. The linear case only happens if we can use the whole array.

Im not sure, but perhaps this can be done in `O(log(N)*k) with N size of array and k < N`, too. We have to use the bin search in a clever way to find leftindex and rightindex in every iteration, such that the possible result range gets smaller in every iteration. This could be easily done, but we have to take care of duplicates, because they could destroy our bin search reductions.